# Using .Find() to find specific text in column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble making sure that my code uses what the end user inputs to find a set of data pertaining to that value and continues with the code there. For example, if the user were to input "V-" as the prefix to the tag number, in theory cell A7 should be selected after the code is complete. However, the code proceeds to run line "MsgBox "No blank cell was found below a tag number with prefix " & str & ".", vbExclamation" and select cell A3 due to the fact that it contains "V-" in the cell. I tried changing the Matchcase to true but it did not help. I also do not want the entered value to be case sensitive.

[image]

Code being used:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim msg As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim str As String, firstcell As String

msg = "Would you like to find the next available tag number?"
result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
If result = vbYes Then
str = Application.InputBox("Enter The Tag Number Prefix ", "Prefix To Tag Number")
If str = "" Then Exit Sub
If Right(str, 1) <> "-" Then str = str & "-"
With Range("A:A")
Set Cell = .Find(str, lookat:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
    firstcell = Cell.Address
    Do
        If Cell.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then
            Cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf InStr(LCase(Cell.Offset(1, 0)), LCase(str)) = 0 Then
            Cell.Select
            MsgBox "No blank cell was found below a tag number with prefix " & str & ".", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
    Loop While Not Cell Is Nothing And firstcell <> Cell.Address
End If
End With
Else
Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @sknteer here is the new post

Comment: The code works fine and select the cell A7 if the user inputs the search string either "v" or "V" or "v-" or "V-". What is not working?

Comment: When I run the code cell A3 is selected

Comment: When I ran it the using your sample data and it selected A7 using all the possible search string as i listed above.

Comment: I'm really not sure how you're getting it to work. Cell A3 is the only selected cell when I search for all the search strings you listed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find cells whose content begins with (e.g.) "V-" then

```
Set Cell = .Find(str & "*", lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
```

For the data below:

```
Sub tester()
    With ActiveSheet.Columns(1)

        Debug.Print .Find("C-" & "*", lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                      MatchCase:=False).Address() '>> $A$3
        Debug.Print .Find("V-" & "*", lookat:=xlWhole, _
                                      MatchCase:=False).Address() '>> $A$5

    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: In replacing your line of code with mine I get a "subscript out of range" run-time error

Comment: On that same line?

Comment: Yes @TimWilliams

Comment: Typo:  `xWhole` should be `xlWhole`

Comment: Yeah I caught that earlier as well. Even with the correction I still got an error

Comment: I don't have any suggestions: I've never seen Find() trigger that specific error.

Comment: Ok I'll keep researching. Thank you for your input!

Comment: If you can share the file (or one which reproduces the issue) I can take a look, but otherwise I'm out of ideas.